# XCode 4 iOS Signing, Build Failed, Build Succeeded

Tags: xcode, ios, build

I get code signing errors in my iOS build. The error isn't intuitive (or consistent) and when the build fails, I simply click "Run" again and the build succeeds and runs fine on the physical iDevice, which is really all that matters!

why does it do this?

Comment: What are the error messages that you're receiving?